# Is there a way to set the time format in xamarin.uitest?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm testing a time picker and I want to test one time the AM,PM format and one time the 24 hours format, is there a way to set android date format via the xamarin.uitest project ? [image: this is how you do it manually]

Comment: Or how can I get the current date format from the device ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below.

```
 [Test]
    public void timePickerTest()
    {
        app.Tap("TimePickerElement");
        SetTimePicker(1, 16, false);
        app.Screenshot("new time set");
        app.Back();
    }

    public void SetTimePicker(int hour, int minute, bool am)
    {
        string hourString = hour.ToString();
        string minuteString = minute.ToString();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime time = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, hour, minute, 0);
        int ampm;

        if (am)
        {
            ampm = 0;
        }
        else ampm = 1;

        if (platform == Platform.iOS)
        {
            app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", time.Hour, "inComponent", 0, "animated", true)); //if time.Hour == 0, than hour is '1'. if time.Hour == 11, than hour is '12'
            app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", time.Minute, "inComponent", 1, "animated", true)); //if time.Minute == 0, than minutes is '1'. if time.Minute == 59, than minutes is '59'
            app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", ampm, "inComponent", 2, "animated", true)); //0 == AM and 1 == PM

        }
        else // Android
        {
            // switch to Text entry for time
            app.Tap("toggle_mode");
            // hour
            app.ClearText();
            app.EnterText(hourString);
            // minute
            app.ClearText("input_minute");
            app.EnterText(minuteString);
            // AM/PM
            if (!am)
            {
                app.Tap("AM"); // opens spinner
                app.Tap("PM"); // changes to PM 
            }
            app.Tap("OK"); // finalize time
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can I set the app to show me a picker with AM PM  or 24 Hours Format?

Comment: The UITtest is used to check the code not to set the format. In the code i provided, use the am parameter to set the value of ampm to check the AM or PM.

Comment: but I have two format picker one is 24 and one is 12, how can I set to know what time format will appear?

Comment: In Xamarin.forms, you could use the custom renderer to set the 24 hours formet. In UITtest, use another bool paramter of `SetTimePicker(int hour, int minute, bool am, bool hour_24)` to check 24 hour first. And then if the value of hour_24 is false, check the am to set the value for ampm.